# Get the list of logical database names in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I want to get a list of logical database names for a given database. I can use the following query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.database_files 
WHERE type_desc = 'ROWS'
```

I want to find an easy and efficient way to do the same using C#. I tried something like this (below) but did not get the desired output.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable databases = con.GetSchema("Databases");

    foreach (DataRow database in databases.Rows)
    {
        String name = database.Field<String>("database_name");
        short dbID = database.Field<short>("dbid");
        DateTime creationDate = database.Field<DateTime>("create_date");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, you dont want a list of all `ROWS` inside your Database?

Comment: @lokusking I just want to get logical names for my database given in the connection string. Selecting the full row from sys.database_files table is equally good.

Comment: Looping go rough the rows of a table requires a round trip each time. You can return just the name and create date for each row in the database as a single object in a single trip. Your question is too narrow for SO. You can see how to do the query elsewhere.

Comment: Why dont you simply fire the above Statement to server and read the results? Like this: `using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select name from sys.database_files where type_desc='ROWS'", con)) {
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) {
          while (reader.Read()) {
            yield return reader.GetString(0);
          }
        }
      }`

Comment: I'm not a C# guy (I know just enough to be dangerous). But I *am* a powershell guy and I'd use SMO for this rather than rolling my own.